# A product of $z_{1},z_{2}\in\mathbb{C}$ is closed under multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

> let $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with multiplication, is it a group?

the operation is associative and $1\in\mathbb{C}$ is the identity.

There is an inverses for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ since the recpical of $z$ is $\frac{1}{z}={\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}i$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ so does $|\frac{1}{z}|$

But why is to closed under multiplication?

Comment: Do you know a theorem about the length of the product of two complex numbers?

Comment: @EthanBolker I know that the absolute value is the length and intuitively it sound right that if we multiply 2 "lengths" of one we get one, but I do know the theorem

Comment: You probably know enough to prove the theorem that the product of the lengths is the length of the product. Give it a try.

Comment: @EthanBolker $|wz|=\sqrt{wz\cdot \bar{wz}}=\sqrt{w\bar{w}z\bar{z}}=\sqrt{w\bar{w}}\sqrt{z\bar{z}}=|w||z|$?

Comment: Sure. Now you know enough to answer your original question. You can do that here, and accept your own answer.